# Congruence if and only if Left and Right Congruence

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, binary-operations, congruence-relations

I have the following problem that I am stuck on:

Let $M$ be a set with a binary operation $\circ$, defined for elements of $M$, and suppose that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $M$. Show that congruence with respect to $\sim$ and $\circ$ holds if and only if left congruence and right congruence with respect to $\sim$ and $\circ$ both hold.

Here are the definitions that my class is using:

The equivalence relation is a *congruence* with respect to $\sim$ and $\circ$ if for all $x,x',y,y'\in M$ with $x\sim x'$ and $y\sim y'$, $(x\circ y)\sim(x'\circ y')$.

*Left congruence*: If $z\in M$ and $x\sim y$, then $(z\circ x)\sim(z\circ y)$.

*Right congruence*: If $z\in M$ and $x\sim y$, then $(x\circ z)\sim(y\circ z)$.

I feel like this should be a really easy proof, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

## If

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
x &\sim& x' \\
x \circ y &\sim& x' \circ y & \text{right congruence} \\
y &\sim& y' \\
x' \circ y &\sim& x' \circ y' & \text{left congruence} \\
x \circ y &\sim& x' \circ y' & \text{equivalence relation is transitive} \\
\end{array}$$

## Only if

Let $x,y,z \in M$ such that $x \sim y$. Also, $z \sim z$ because equivalence relation is reflexive. Then, by the given assumption, we have $x \circ z \sim y \circ z$ (right congruence) and $z \circ x \sim z \circ y$ (left congruence).

## Remarks

Note how the two properties of equivalence relation are used here. Also, note how symmetry is not used. We can construct a relation that is reflexive and transitive but not symmetric, on a set of two elements $S = \{a,b\}$, as follows: $R = \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,b)\}$, i.e. for all $x,y \in S$, $xRy$ if and only if $(x,y) \ne (b,a)$.

#### Reflexive

We have $aRa$ and $bRb$, so $R$ is reflexive.

#### Symmetric

We have $aRb$ but not $bRa$, so $R$ is not symmetric.

#### Transitive

We have $8$ statements to check:

- $(x,y,z) = (a,a,a): aRa \land aRa \implies aRa$ (true and true implies true)
- $(x,y,z) = (a,a,b): aRa \land aRb \implies aRb$ (true and true implies true)
- $(x,y,z) = (a,b,a): aRb \land bRa \implies aRa$ (true and false implies true)
- $(x,y,z) = (a,b,b): aRb \land bRb \implies aRb$ (true and true implies true)
- $(x,y,z) = (b,a,a): bRa \land aRa \implies bRa$ (false and true implies false)
- $(x,y,z) = (b,a,b): bRa \land aRb \implies bRb$ (false and true implies true)
- $(x,y,z) = (b,b,a): bRb \land bRa \implies bRa$ (true and false implies false)
- $(x,y,z) = (b,b,b): bRb \land bRb \implies bRb$ (true and true implies true)

#### Congruence

There are 16 binary operations that can be defined on $S$. I'll only pick one:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\circ&a&b\\\hline
a&a&a\\\hline
b&b&b
\end{array}$$

The verification that $\circ$ and $\sim$ satisfy all three of left congruence, right congruence, and congruence, is left to the reader as an exercise, ending this exploration.

Comment: In the "if" part, are you assuming that it is a full congruence or just a left and right congruence?

Comment: @A.S.Hopkins I added the third line in the "if" part, where I assumed that it is a left and right congruence and proved that it is a full congruence.

Comment: Thanks! Also, in the "only if" part, what is the given assumption that you reference?

Comment: In the "only if" part, I assumed a full congruence and proved left and right congruence.

Comment: But how does the statement prove it is a full congruence? It just jumps to saying that it has to be a left and right congruence.

Comment: Which part are you referring to?

Comment: How do you go from $x\sim y$ to $z\sim z$ to $(x\circ z)\sim(y\circ z)$?

Comment: @A.S.Hopkins I apply the assumption with change of variables $(x,x',y,y') \mapsto (x,y,z,z)$ (the confusion stems from having $y$ meaning two different things)